# Laravel Regular Expression in Relationships

Tags: regex, laravel, relationship

Using Laravel, I am trying to get relations of a model using regular expressions rather than matching local and foreign keys. Is this possible?

For example Let's say I have the following Models with databases.

**Vehicle.php**

```
+----+--------------------------------+
| ID | type                           |
|----|--------------------------------+
|  1 | red bicycle 11042017 out       |
|----|--------------------------------+
|  2 | green trike 25082017 out       |
|----|--------------------------------+
|  3 | bicycle 12042017 in            |
|----|--------------------------------+
|  4 | red trike 25052017 in          |
|----|--------------------------------+
|  5 | pink hover board 11042017 lost |
|----|--------------------------------+
```

**Reference.php**

```
+----+-------------+------------------------------+
| ID | reference   | pattern                      |
|----|-------------+------------------------------+
|  1 | Bicycle     | (.*)?bicyle(.*)(out|in)      |
|----|-------------+------------------------------+
|  2 | Trike       | (.*)?trike(.*)(out|in)       |
|----|-------------+------------------------------+
|  3 | Hover Board | (.*)hover board(.*)(out|in)  |
+----|-------------+------------------------------+
```

I would like to run something like the following query...

```
$vehicles = Vehicle::with('reference')->get();
```

... and have the vehicle relationship method something like...

```
public function reference()
{
    return $this->hasMany(
        Reference::class, 
        preg_match([reference pattern], [vehicle.type]);
    )
}
```

... which would return.

```
+----+--------------------------------+-------------+
| ID | type                           | reference   |
|----|--------------------------------+-------------+
|  1 | red bicycle 11042017 out       | Bike        |
|----|--------------------------------+-------------+
|  2 | green trike 25082017 out       | Trike       |
|----|--------------------------------+-------------+
|  3 | bicycle 12042017 in            | Bicycle     |
|----|--------------------------------+-------------+
|  4 | red trike 25052017 in          | Trike       |
|----|--------------------------------+-------------+
|  5 | pink hover board 11042017 lost | Hover Board |
|----|--------------------------------+-------------+
```

The important thing is the related model contains the regex pattern, not the parent model.

Can this be achieved. I had been banging my head against a wall for a couple of days now, and apart for a headache, I have not achieved anything.

Thanks

Comment: You may want to consider writing this as a join on a regex condition instead.

Comment: Are you able to provide an example @Joel? I am still struggling considering the regular expression pattern is in the joined table.  Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not - I haven't written anything like that.

Comment: Why go through all that trouble... why not add a a simple computed attribute to your model? All the information you need is in the vehicle table... it is not like you need anything from the reference table except the pattern... is this what I am missing, you want the pattern to be configurable in that table? Many other ways to skin that cat...

Comment: @Serge. Well I also need the value in the reference column of the  "Reference" table as well as the pattern

Comment: Is this possible or is there a better way of achieving the results I require with my table structure? I do have the ability to change the 'reference' table schema, but not the 'vehicle'